# I'm trying to print international characters on Embarcadero Dev-C++ but they always come out wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    printf("ééé");
}
```

My output is always `Ã©Ã©Ã©`. It does work on the official dev `c++` compiler but I can't get it to work on this one

Comment: It works just fine with gcc. Your issue is probably using a different terminal emulator with a non utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Or, rather, the IDE is using UTF-8. To verify, modify your code to print to a file, and let us know how that looks.

Comment: Try `wprintf(L"ééé");`. Your terminal is using iso-8859-something and your compiler is using utf-8.